# How to do a ORDER BY with an expression in Magento Collections

Tags: sql, magento, collections, sql-order-by

I already know how to do a simple order by with a Magento collection. But this time I want to do something like this,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE filed LIKE '%abc%' 
ORDER BY  SUBSTRING(field, 1, 2) DESC LIMIT 10
```

So how can I add SUBSTRING function to my order by clause? Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento models have a `setOrder()` method for simple attribute sorting:

```
$oCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->setOrder('name_of_attribute_to_sort', 'ASC');
```

They don't have a dedicated method for sorting by expressions like yours, but Magento collections use a `Varien_Db_Select` instance extending `Zend_Db_Select`, so you could use its `order()` and `limit()` methods:

```
$oCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$oCollection
    ->getSelect()
    ->order(array('SUBSTRING(field, 1, 2) DESC'))
    ->limit(10);
```